# Auto-Homeomorphism of R making polynomials discontinuous

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual topology and let $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=\max\{1,x\}$.  Does there exist a homeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi\circ f = g$?  Obviously no such diffeomorphism can exist but it's not clear that this is the not the case for a homeomorphism...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because then $1 = \max(1, -2) = (\phi \circ f)(-2) = (\phi \circ f)(2) = \max(1, 2) = 2$.

Even if we consider $f \circ \phi$, it cannot be done. $\phi$ must be continous and injective, so it must be strictly monotone. Then $\lim_{x \to -\infty} (f \circ \phi)(x) = \infty$, but $\lim_{x \to -\infty} \max(1, x) = 1$.

This also shows that $(\phi^{-1} \circ f \circ \phi)(x) = \max(x, 1)$ is impossible.

Comment: I guess a similar argument would hold for the non-existence of $f\circ \phi$?

Comment: @Zorn'sLama Please see my edit.